# Prototype Design Pattern

Tags: c#, design-patterns

Why I need to use Prototype Design Pattern ? Instead of that I can directly assign that value right ? for example

as per Prototype Design Pattern we have to clone like :

```
Typist typistCopy = (Typist)typist.Clone();
```

same I can do as:

```
Typist typistCopy = typist;
```

What's importance of Prototype Design Pattern here ?

Comment: Because those two operations do different things.  Which one do you want to do in your scenario?

Comment: @David Clone will copy it's properties values right ? how it will differ could you explain ?

Comment: How is `Typist` declared, is it a struct or a class? As others have said, the two statements does different things. They *may* end up having the set result if the type is a struct (value type) and depending on what the `Clone` method does, but we need to know for sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two operations you demonstrate do different things.  Which one you need depends on what you want to do.

This *does not* create a copy/clone of the object:

```
Typist typistCopy = typist;
```

All it does it create a new *variable* which references the *same object* in memory.  After executing that line of code, you still have only *one* `Typist` object.  You just have two variables referencing it.  Any changes made to one variable will be reflected in both, because they both reference the same object.

On the other hand, this creates a *copy* or *clone* of the object:

```
Typist typistCopy = (Typist)typist.Clone();
```

(Or, at least, allows the object itself to decide if a copy/clone is necessary and performs its own encapsulated logic as to what that means for the object.)

After executing that line of code, you now have *two* `Typist` objects which can be used and manipulated independently of one another.  Any change made to one variable will not be reflected in the other, because they reference different objects.

Answer (score 0):

To add a real world analogy:

```
Page paper = (Page)yourPaper.Clone();
```

This creates a **copy**. Now there's two pages of paper, you have your original and somebody was handed the copy.

```
Page paper = yourPaper;
```

No copy was made. You have a page of paper and somebody else grabbed it, too. Now you both hold onto that single page of paper.

You need to decide what you want.